# Change position of a circle?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want a circle object to change position, I would imagine that I do the same as I do with markers -

```
marker.setPosition(latlng);
```

So -

```
circle.setPosition(latlng);
```

But this doesn't work. The marker changes position, but the circle doesn't. All I can find is this link - https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/mvcfun

Would that seem like the best way to go about this? I've not had a proper ready through it, so I'm going to try implement the above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change the center property of the circle to move it ([it doesn't have a position property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#CircleOptions))

```
circle.setCenter(latlng)
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle

Answer (score 0):

Just an extension for above answer

```
 MyLocationCircle.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude));
```